# trying to run my Gmail account through Thunderbird

Tags: windows

I am trying to run my Gmail account through Thunderbird. I cannot access my Thunderbird mail because it is connected to the previous Internet provider and they have already discontinued my account. I have existing messages, folders and contacts in my Thunderbird that I need, but when I open Thunderbird, this message appears: "Could not connect to mail server - connection was refused." I would greatly appreciate assistance on how to keep my Thunderbird content and use Gmail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're connecting to `imap.googlemail.com`, port `993`. Also make sure you're using SSL/TLS connection security and password authentication. If you have two-factor authentication on your account, be prepared to enter an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for Thunderbird.